# How to know whether to use "a" or "b" substitution when solving for ellipse's center

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

If I have the following problem:
`Vertices: (1,5),(1,-3)` and `c=3`
With the given vertices I know that `h=1`
I first try to solve for `k` to finish solving for my center. To this I can use the following format:
`(h,k+-a)` or `(h,k+-b)`

If I do not know whether the given vertices are from a major/minor axis, so how do I know whether I should substitute for `a` or `b` when solving for `k`?

Comment: The center will always be at the center of _either_ the mayor or minor axis. Hence the center is at the midpoint between $(1,5)$ and $(1,-3)$, so your center is at $\left(\frac{1+1}{2}, \frac{5 -3}{2}\right) = (1,1)$.

Comment: I was able to figure out the center, but I was unsure of carrying on with the problem because I was still unsure of whether to substitute "a" or "b" when solving as I described above. I just went with using "a" and got the correct answer. However, that question still lingers in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any ellipse, by definition, the minor *and* major axis have the center of the ellipse as their midpoint. Recalling that the midpoint between $2$ points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is given by
$$
\left(\frac{x_1 +x_2}{2},\frac{y_1 +y_2}{2}\right)
$$
we see that the center of the ellipse has to be at
$$
C = \left(\frac{1+1}{2}, \frac{5 -3}{2}\right) = (1,1)
$$
So, the equation of our ellipse has the form
$$
\frac{(x-1)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-1)^2}{b^2} = 1 \tag{1}
$$
We'll also note that the distance between the 2 vertices given is
$$
d\left[(1,-3),(1,5)\right] = \sqrt{(1-1)^2 + (5-(-3))^2} = 8
$$
Now, to find out if these vertices correspond to the major or minor axis, we recall that, since the vertices need to be *on* the ellipse, they need to satisfy equation $(1)$ is we plug them in. Choosing one of the vertices, let's say $(1,5)$, by substituting in $(1)$ we get
\begin{align}
&\frac{(1-1)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(5-1)^2}{b^2} = 1\\
\implies&\frac{4^2}{b^2} = 1 \\
\implies &b = 4 \tag{2}
\end{align}
And recalling the relation
$$
c^2 = a^2 - b^2
$$
we can find the value of $a$ to be
\begin{align}
a &= \sqrt{c^2 + b^2}\\
&\overset{\color{blue}{(2)}}{=}\sqrt{c^2 + 16}\\
&= \sqrt{9 + 16}\\
& = 5
\end{align}
From here we get that the major axis has to have length $2a = 2(5) = 10$ and the minor axis has lenght $2b = 2(4) = 8$. So since the distance between our vertices is $8$, it has to be the case that they correpond to vertices on the *minor* axis.

---

Another way of looking at it is as follows. If we just guess that the vertices correspond to the major axis, recalling that the distance between them is $8$ we see that from this assumption we get $a = \frac{8}{2} = 4$. But using the relation $c^2 = a^2 -b^2$ we get that $b$ has length
$$
b = \sqrt{a^2 -c^2} = \sqrt{4^2 - 3^2} = \sqrt{7}
$$
And since we now know both $a$ and $b$, we see by equation $(1)$ that the equation of this assumed ellipse is given by
$$
\frac{(x-1)^2}{4^2} + \frac{(y-1)^2}{\sqrt{7}^2} = 1
$$
However, if we plug in one of the vertices (let's say $(1,5)$) into the equation above we get that
\begin{align}
&\frac{(1-1)^2}{4^2} + \frac{(5-1)^2}{\sqrt{7}^2} = 1 \\
\implies & \frac{4^2}{7} = 1 \\
\implies & 16 = 7
\end{align}
since this is clearly a contradiction, the conclusion is that the point $(1,5)$ is *not* on the ellipse! But this is a problem, since by it being a vertex it needs to be on the ellipse. Hence the solution where the points correspond to the major axis is impossible.

---

In conclusion, the condition that $c=3$ ***forces*** the vertices to be of the minor axis, and if we were to assume that they correspond to a major axis, we would get an impossible solution. We can visually verify this by plotting the 2 equations we get from assuming each case

[image]

where the green ellipse is given by the equation
$$
\frac{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}{5^{2}}+\frac{\left(y-1\right)^{2}}{4^{2}}=1
$$
and the red one is given by
$$
\frac{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}{4^{2}}+\frac{\left(y-1\right)^{2}}{\sqrt{7}^2}=1
$$
both of them satisfy that $c=3$, that their center is at $(1,1)$ and that one of their axis has length $8$, but only one of the 2 solutions passes through the vertices we're given.